# How to completely uninstall devstack and reinstall it?

Tags: openstack, opendaylight

I am trying to install devstack from the following link:

https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OVSDB:OVSDB_OpenStack_Guide

However, ./stack.sh always throws some error. Is there any way I can remove all the configurations of devstack and redo it?

This is the error I am getting:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /opt/stack/keystone
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
+ exit_trap
+ local r=1
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ kill_spinner
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+ generate-subunit 1454006489 226 fail
+ [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+ /home/aditya/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2016-01-28-184515.txt for details
+ exit 1
```

Comment: run 'yum upgrade' and then  try again. That should resolve the pip issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the same docs, anywhere that it says yum install use `yum remove`.
After that check if ~/DevStack still exists. If it is there run `rm -fr ~/DevStack`

(You could probably leave java and @standard on your system)

Though I'm left thinking if this tutorial starts with `Boot from the Fedora Net Install .iso - Select the minimal package - Select your hard disk layout` you might just want to start over...

I don't think OpenFlow installs it looks like it just compiles so you might want to delete the zip and the extracted folder and re-download...

What error are you getting from stack.sh?

Comment: Literally just a dash? That's some brutality.

Comment: If you haven't done anything else on that installation instance just start from scratch...

Comment: There was a typo in my reply. Kindly look at the edited text in my question.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `unstack.sh` script is meant for that. So you just need to be in the devstack folder and fire the `./unstack.sh` and sit back. Once finished you can try to reinstall with ``./stack.sh```

I am assuming you are using the devstack repo found on github https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack.git

Comment: I was totally wrong, the unstack.sh script is not used to uninstalled but to unstack before you reboot for example. On the other end, ```clean.sh``` seems to uninstall everything including deps.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone has the same problem. The solution is to go to :

```
~/devstack/tools/cap-pip.txt
```

And set the value **pip** to the last version of pip, like this :

```
pip==18
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete all existing folders and use this document to install it again. Remember to clone it to a new place this time. Don't override it. And if error persists do email me or comment below. I was stuck with the same problem had to reinstall ubuntu for it but then i figured this solution. [DevStack Installation All-In-One Single Machine](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/guides/single-machine.html)

Comment: i did try this, but I had to reinstall Ubuntu :/

Answer (score -1):

There is no perfect solution to uninstall Devstack. Reinstalling Ubuntu is the only way through.

Comment: This is not true. You not being able to do it is not the same as it being impossible.